# Exercise 8.12 from Richard Bass' Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $f$ is integrable. Prove that
$$ \int |f(x+h) - f(x)| dx \to 0 $$
as $h \to 0.$

The hint in the back of the book says that I should apply the following theorem:

Suppose $f$ is a Lebesgue measurable real-valued integrable function on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\epsilon >0.$ Then there exists a continuous function $g$ with compact support such that
$$ \int |f-g| < \epsilon.$$

I don't readily see how I can use this theorem to solve the exercise. How is this useful?

Comment: You play the usual game of adding and subtracting a certain function and then applying the triangle inequality to start. Continuity and compact support of $g$ takes you the rest of the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to prove that $\limsup_{h\to0}\int\lvert f(x+h)-f(x)\rvert\,dx=0$. Now, for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $g\in C_c(\Bbb R)$ such that $$\int\lvert f(x)-g(x)\rvert\,dx\le\varepsilon$$ Therefore for all $\varepsilon$ there is some $g$ such that for all $h$ \begin{align}&\int\lvert f(x+h)-f(x)\rvert\,dx\le \\&\le\int\lvert f(x+h)-g(x+h)\rvert\,dx+\int\lvert g(x)-f(x)\rvert\,dx+\int\lvert g(x+h)-g(x)\rvert\,dx\le\\&\le 2\varepsilon+\int \lvert g(x+h)-g(x)\rvert\,dx\end{align}

Now, by continuity $g(x+h)-g(x)\to 0$ as $h\to0$ and therefore, by dominated convergence, $$\lim_{h\to0}\int\lvert g(x+h)-g(x)\rvert\,dx= 0$$

Therefore, for all $\varepsilon>$, $$\limsup_{h\to0}\int\lvert f(x+h)-f(x)\rvert\,dx\le \limsup_{h\to 0} 2\varepsilon +\int\lvert g(x+h)-g(x)\rvert\,dx=2\varepsilon$$

And therefore $\limsup_{h\to0}\int\lvert f(x+h)-f(x)\rvert\,dx=0$.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let us define $g \in C^0_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $K=\overline{supp(g)}$. Then $K$ is compact.

If $0 < h < 1$ and $J_h(x)=|g(x+h)-g(x)|$ then we have that $supp(J_h) \subset \overline{K+B(0,1)}$ and thus $|J_h(x)| \leq 2\|g\|_{\infty}\chi_{\overline{K+B(0,1)}}(x)$ which allows us to use Dominated Convergence to conclude $\lim_{h\to0}\int|g(x+h)-g(x)|dx=0$ and from this the conclusion is easy.